# Is there anyway, we can convert Rate ratio to Odds ratio

Tags: meta-analysis

I am doing a meta-analysis of longitudinal data in which few studies have OR as summary estimate while others have rate ratio (incidence). Except for the summary estimate, there is no heterogeneity between the studies. It doesn't seem sensible for me to conduct separate meta-analyses just for this reason. I will be grateful if somebody can advise

Comment: Are the base rates listed anywhere? Can you contact the corresponding authors?

Comment: dear gung no, i could have calculated OR if the descriptives were provided.  I have tried contacting the authors but only very few of them responded.

Answer (score 1):

There is a method for going in the other direction
@Article{,
    title = {Converting Odds Ratio to Relative Risk in Cohort Studies
      with Partial Data Information},
    author = {Zhu Wang},
    journal = {Journal of Statistical Software},
    year = {2013},
    volume = {55},
    number = {5},
    pages = {1--11},
    url = {http://www.jstatsoft.org/v55/i05/},
  }
Not sure if this helps you as it would mean working in the relative risk scale. It has been implemented as an R package - search for orsk in the list of packages.

Comment: hi, thanks for sharing your knowledge. I had a chance to look at this article  and also the websites that offer online conversion from OR to relative risk but I need to convert Incidence rate ratio (not relative risk) to OR...can we consider IRR as equivalent to OR when the years of observation is same in both the exposed and unexposed groups?